# reference variables and objects

Tags: oop, object, inheritance, reference, polymorphism

I wanted to know why this did not work, as in why didn't the compiler invoke the restart method within the computer class...

Consider the following scenario:

I have 3 classes as shown below:

```
public class Computer {
public int compStatus = 0; //0 means off, 1 means on.

public void turnOn(){
    this.compStatus = 1;
}

public void turnOff(){
    this.compStatus = 0;
}

public void restart(){
    if(compStatus ==1){
    System.out.println("Turning off");
    compStatus = 0;
    System.out.println("Turning on");
    compStatus = 1;
    System.out.println("Restart successful");
    }
}


}
```

Now the sub-class:

```
public class Macintosh extends Computer {

public void openXCode(){
    if(compStatus == 1){
        System.out.println("XCode Compiler opened.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Mac is off.");
    }
}

public void restart(){
    System.out.println("Mac restarted");
}

}
```

The tester class:

```
public class CompTest {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Computer testObj = new Macintosh();
    testObj.turnOn();
    testObj.restart();  ///ERROR HERE
}
}
```

I am aware that the compiler checks if the restart method is in the class of the reference variable 'Computer' not the class of the actual object at the other end of the reference 'macintosh'. So if what I have said is true, why is the restart method not invoked?

Comment: What is your expected output from this code? `Turning off` `Turning on` `Restart successful` ?

Comment: @MattMartin I would've expected the compiler to invoke the super classes restart method, I know you would normally do super.restart(), but I am curious as to why the Computer classes restart method wasn't invoked.

Comment: Try `((Computer)testObj).restart();` at the problem line. Is this the behavior you were expecting? If so, I can write you a full answer explaining why this works and why your original code didn't do what you expected. As far as I understand, you are aware that you can do it like this, but just aren't sure why the original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the base class method in order to actually restart.  Your method is just hiding the base method.  You should override the method and then call it base.restart to do what you want.

Comment: The restart method has already been overridden in the sub-class...,

What is my method and what is the base method, you are not clearly specifying which method you are referring to when using these terms... 'my' and 'base'.

Comment: super.restart();  wasnt very clear what i was trying to convey i guess.

Comment: How comes testObj.restart(), doesn't use the super-classes restart method, I would've assumed it would do so, if the compiler only checks for methods in the reference variables class (super).

Comment: your calling macintosh restart method without calling your derived classes method restart which needs to be called with the super keyword.

Comment: your hiding it by implementing in.  Remove it and the derived classes method will get called.